# VBA Averageifs with dynamic criteria range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use `WorksheetFunction.Averageifs` and have the following code:

```
Range("C1:C676") = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Sheets(modelName).Range("M:M"), _ 
Sheets(modelName).Range("G:G"), Sheets(wsName).Range("A1"))
```

The problem i'm running into is that the last criteria range does not run through the full column of data in `Sheets(wsName).Range("A1:676")` to accord with the correct row in column C in the initial range; it just keeps using A1. I.e when the initial row is C82 for example, the final criteria range should be `Sheets(wsName).Range("A82")`.

How can I change this to move dynamically?

Comment: how will the initial row be defined each time? And is your desire to really set every cell from `C1:C676` to the average of all the cells defined in the function?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am imagining it works just like when you do `range("A1:A100").formula =` in the way it mimics doing a formula in A1 then copying down the formula to all the cells. That would copy down the formula range, e.g. =A1+B1 becomes A2+B2, A3+B3 etc.

Comment: If that's the case, don't use it like you have it.  Do `Range("C1:C676").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS([conditions])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the same range in the criteria and use `Application.AverageIfs` and not `WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs`:

```
Range("C1:C676") = 
Application.AverageIfs(Sheets(modelName).Range("M:M"), _ 
Sheets(modelName).Range("G:G"), Sheets(wsName).Range("A1:A676"))
```

Alternatively you could put a formula into those cells and then replace it with the resulting values, or use `Evaluate`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That worked. Why does it not work with the full syntax? I thought I had it written in the 'correct' way.

Comment: It just doesn't - there is some internal difference. You also were only including one criteria cell, not the full range.